# How can I know all the tuesdays of a given month?

Tags: java

For instance in Sept I would need:

1,8,15,22 and 29

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (naive) solution I can see is:

Get a Calendar (Calendar.getInstance())

Set the year, month, date etc (zero out other fields).

Then iterate adding one to the date (stop if you're not in the correct month - calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))

while iterating, if calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY then increment the Tuesday counter.

Comment: Well I wouldn't increment the counter but add it to a list or something.  I've coded your algorithm and runs fine. Thanks

Comment: You really needed Stack Overflow to come up with *that* solution? You’re kidding me, right?

Answer (score 7):

Look up the [Doomsday Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) - you should be able to apply that algorithm to your problem.

Comment: Excellent...many years ago I came across this algorithm but did not know what it was called so I could not find it back.

Comment: If this calculation needs to be done a lot, then the Doomsday algorithm will probably be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

As per daveb answer I've got:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import static  java.util.Calendar.*;

public class DiasDelMes {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        Calendar calendar = getInstance();

        calendar.set( DAY_OF_MONTH, 1  );

        int month = calendar.get( MONTH );

        while( calendar.get( MONTH ) == month ) { 

            if( calendar.get( DAY_OF_WEEK ) == TUESDAY ) {
                 System.out.println( calendar.get( DAY_OF_MONTH ) ) ;
            }

            calendar.add( DAY_OF_MONTH , 1 ); 
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer for such question but to solve it in Java 8.

Here is my solution:

```
public Stream<Temporal> listAllDaysInMonthIterative(Month month, DayOfWeek dow) {
    List<Temporal> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(Year.now().getValue(), month.getValue(), 1);

    TemporalAdjuster adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow);

    while (date.with(adjuster).get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR) == month.getValue()) {
        date = date.with(adjuster);
        dates.add(date);
        adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.next(dow);
    }

    return dates.stream();
}
```

Run:

```
@Test
public void testMondaysInMonth() {

    MonthLengthReporter reporter = new MonthLengthReporter();
    Stream days = reporter.listAllDaysInMonthIterative(Month.MARCH, DayOfWeek.MONDAY);

    days.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```